# Can I connect assembla to Github Desktop in windows?

Tags: git, github-for-windows, assembla

I'm thinking is this possible like cloning my whole repository in assembla to my desktop through the use Github Desktop app and committing changes to it?

Comment: Use the git-bash/git-shell (or git-powershell) provided by GH for windows.

Comment: Ok I'll try it and post back if succeed. thanks